# specialization of a template method using a template type

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

Given the following snippet:

```
struct A {
  template <class T >
  void doSomething(T t) {
    std::cout << "doSomething() with " << t << std::endl;
  }
};
template <class T>
struct B {
  T val;
};
```

How can I specialize `A::doSomething()` for a template `B<T>` ? The following "naïve" attempt does not compile but might explain what I want to achieve:

```
template<class T>
void A::doSomething(B<T> t){
  std::cout << "doSomething specialized for B: " << t.val << std::endl;
}
```

Is what I want to achieve possible ? and if it is what is the syntax ?

**UPDATE**

Reading this thread I found an alternative way of achieving what I want:
[Specialize a template with a template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542597/specialize-a-template-with-a-template?rq=1)

As the syntax is not always easy with templates, here is a working example with different levels of specializations:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

namespace details {
template<class T> struct Impl;
}
struct A {
  template <class T >
  void doSomething(T t) {
    details::Impl<T>::f(t);
  }
};
template <class T>
struct B {
  T val;
};
namespace details {
template<class T>
struct Impl {
  static void f(T t){std::cout << "default" << std::endl;}
};
template<template<class> class U, class T>
struct Impl<U<T> > {
  static void f(U<T> b){std::cout << "default for U<T>"<< std::endl;}
};
template<>
void Impl<double>::f(double d) {
  std::cerr << "doSomething with double " << d << std::endl;
}
template<class T>
struct Impl<B<T> > {
  static void f(B<T> b);
};
template<class T> 
void Impl<B<T> >::f(B<T> b) {
  std::cerr << "doSomething with B<T> " << b.val << std::endl;
}
template<> 
void Impl<B<int> >::f(B<int> b) {
  std::cerr << "doSomething with B<int> " << b.val << std::endl;
}
}
template<class T>
struct C {
  T toto;
};
int main() {
  A a;
  a.doSomething(12.0);
  B<double> b;
  b.val = 42.0;
  a.doSomething(b);
  B<int> b2;
  b2.val = 42.0;
  a.doSomething(b2);
  C<int> c;
  a.doSomething(c);
  std::vector<int> v;
  a.doSomething(v);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Partial template specialization works only for classes. See gfor example http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm

Comment: What you're doing is overloading (which is the preferred way) but you also have to declare the function in the class `template<class T>
void doSomething(B<T>)`

Comment: Possible workaround: Use a template class with a single static member function. `template <blah> struct doSomething {static void func(blah) {blah}}` You can make a partial specialization for such class.

Comment: All the suggestions to enclose the function into template class fail to take into account lack of automatic template type deduction in such a case.

Answer (score 2):

You can't (partially) specialize it, but you can overload the function. Like following (i made the function a free function to ease on typing):

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T> struct B { };

template<class T> void doSomething(B<T> t) {  std::cout << "B\n"; }

template <class T> void doSomething(T t) { std::cout << "T\n"; }

int main() {
    int x;
    B<double> k;

    doSomething(x);
    doSomething(k);
}
```

Output:

```
T
B
```

Comment: thanks, but I can't use a free function (struct A was simplified for the example), and this solution imposes that I declare the two overloaded variants in the the struct.

Comment: @Charles, yes. Well, than you have no choice but to forgo overloading and use partial specialization of the class.